# using odata function isof with web api

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, odata

I am using OData with web api and attempting to make queries based on type specifics. What I want is to serve a query that looks something like this(where the bolded text isn't syntactically correct but describes what I'm looking to do after asserting the type):

*../Supplier?$filter=isof(Product, namespace.ToyProduct)*&Product.ratedAge eq 5

however when I try doing this with the [Queryable] attribute and inheriting from ODataController I get a **method not supported error** with regards to the isof. Is there any way to get the method supported? I have tried adding AllowedFunctions.All to the Queryable attribute but this didn't work.

I am able to use the ODataQueryOptions to check if isof is included in filter and use my own method to check, however it's rather messy and will probably become worse after allowing extra filtering, if a better solution exists that would be awesome!

uncompiled code as it stands currently:

```
public class SupplierController : ODataController {
    [Queryable(AllowedFunctions = AllowedFunctions.All)]
    public PageResult<Supplier> Get(ODataQueryOptions<Supplier> queryOptions) {

        // doesn't work, method not supported
        //var queryableSuppliers = queryOptions.ApplyTo(_repository.All());  

        // works but messy method.
        var queryableSuppliers = MyIsOfMethod(queryOptions.Filter) 

        return new PageResult<ObjectType>(
            results as IEnumerable<ObjectType>,
            Request.GetNextPageLink(),
            Request.GetInlineCount());

    }
}
```

Comment: I have a solution to emilt the ``OfType`` call to the query in order to simulate the ``isof`` function.  See https://github.com/schungx/WebApi-OData for the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't support isof and cast functions in web api. We instead support the new cast syntax using separate segments. Your query would look like this with the new syntax,

`../Supplier?$filter=Product/namespace.ToyProduct/ratedAge eq 5`

Comment: Could you provide a link to documentation about this new syntax and how to use it? I was having the same problem as the OP, but I could not manage to make your suggestion work. I was using the other "overload" of the `isof` function, which only takes a fully qualified type name in single quotes. Also, what is the reason for not supporting it in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

I Do not think the answer match with the question.
The original query in question is:

```
../Supplier?$filter=isof(Product, namespace.ToyProduct)&Product.ratedAge eq 5
```

I guess it actually means to be:

```
../Supplier?$filter=isof(Product, namespace.ToyProduct)%20and%20Product.ratedAge eq 5
```

Anyway, it is filter to retrieve entities in a specific derived type or its sub type.
The answer does not doing that.